# tcpdump: (all BPF devices are busy) - How to solve this

Tags: networking, sniffing, tcpdump

I was running tcpdump and then after some time I got this error:

```
tcpdump: (all BPF devices are busy)
```

I am not sure why? I killed all tcpdump processes, in case that this had something to do with it, but it did not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't realy an infosec question, but did you wait long after killing the processes?
In most code this is for the reason it describes - there's not a handle 
 ... honestly, sometimes at that point a reboot is quicker than debugging the 'why' if it's a machine where you can do so, did you do so?

can you ls /dev/bpf* on your host (if that's where they show up? ) 
For those, have you tried grepping lsof output for them ?